# Stop close session in NSURL

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

When I'm sending request (POST) to special URL.
With a simple code I able to login (with username/password) to the site (authorization page).
Because the site have SESSION feature, if I send another request, the site again will back to the first page (authorization page).

I don't know how I able to fix it.

Comment: Is that session cookie based or does it use a GET- or POST-parameter to keep itself alive?

Comment: no I haven't done any cookie in their! The most I have to post things.

Comment: your comment does not make any sense. You should find out how the session is kept alive on your server. There are three alternatives; GET, POST or COOKIE. This has nothing to do with your initial request but the method of keeping a session active.

Comment: I don't know "how the session is kept alive on THE server".